# How to alter user defined table types

Tags: sql-server, alter, user-defined-types

I have already tried to alter the user defined table types but it is not working with alter commend.

```
alter TYPE [dbo].[GriDDateTab] AS TABLE(
    [Application [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LandDist] [char](2) NULL,
    [Land] [char](3) NULL,
    [LandVi] [char](4) NULL)
```

Comment: If you have even *looked* at the [official MSDN SQL Server Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879314.aspx) - you'd see there **is no** `ALTER TYPE` statement. Just isn't there. You need to drop your type and re-create it fresh.

Comment: Change `[Application` to `[Application]` ;).

Comment: @marc_s - even if the OP *had* looked at the docs you cite, his question was not invalid.  While the syntax "ALTER TYPE" is not listed there as an option, it would have been foolish for him to discount the idea that there was some other syntactic variation required to achieve the outcome.  While there must be good reasons for the SQL devs to not allow this, It certainly does seem ridiculous on the surface that this is not possible.  Being first required to drop all referencing objects is pretty draconian.

Comment: @ChrisRogers: absolutely - the lack of `ALTER TYPE` really renders the user-defined types almost useless - at least for me

Answer (score 8):

You have to drop and recreate. That means if you have any references (eg stored procedures) using the type, that reference must be removed first.

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is that you have to drop and re-create as SQL server does not (at least not up until 2012 support this.

The good news is that stored procedures and functions should pick up table type changes on the fly with no need to drop and re-create.

Comment: I do not believe the good news is true, see the other answers

Comment: -- the following script demostrates that (at least from 2014 onwards it works

create type t_demo as table (intfield int)
go

create procedure p_demo 
as
declare @t t_demo
begin
  select * from @t
end
go

exec p_demo
go

drop type  t_demo 
go

create type t_demo as table (intfield int, textfield nvarchar(50))
go

exec p_demo

Comment: @EdGreen - It doesn't seem to register as a dependency unless it's a parameter. EG, define your sproc this way: create procedure p_demo (@t t_demo READONLY) as begin select * from @t end go. And you'll see the problem.  Meh. Not sure why. I can't find anything about dependencies ONLY being in the param defs.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly everything said is true, however you can save yourself some time by by going to the context menu of the table type->Script User-Defined Table Type as..

If you use DROP and CREATE To Query Window you can make your edits and click execute.

You will still have to recreate references in other Programmability structures.